# Trying to get the correct context

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-asynctask

i am following [this](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822#comment-9065) tutorial to implement `google direction API`. In the tutorial the `onclick` and all codes related to inputing data are in a fragmentActivity. But i would like to use a fragment. i would like to know how to change the asyncTask class in the tutorial so that it is using the right Context to find my fragment.
Here is my attempt.

```
public class GetDirectionsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Map<String, Object>, Object, ArrayList<LatLng>>
{
    public static final String USER_CURRENT_LATLNG = "user_current_latlng";
    public static final String DESTINATION_LATLNG = "destination_latlng";
    public static final String DIRECTIONS_MODE = "directions_mode";
    private MainActivity activity;
    private Closest fragment;
    private Exception exception;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public GetDirectionsAsyncTask(Closest fragment, MainActivity activity)
    {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.fragment.getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Calculating directions");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<LatLng> result)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (exception == null)
        {
            fragment.handleGetDirectionsResult(result);
        }
        else
        {
            processException();
        }
    }
 @Override
    protected ArrayList<LatLng> doInBackground(Map<String, Object>... params)
    {
        Map<String, Object> paramMap = params[0];
        try
        {
            LatLng fromPosition = (LatLng) paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LATLNG);
            LatLng toPosition = (LatLng) paramMap.get(DESTINATION_LATLNG);
            GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
            Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, (String)paramMap.get(DIRECTIONS_MODE));
            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints = md.getDirection(doc);
            return directionPoints;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void processException()
    {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error retriving data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The minute it needs to know the Context, it crashes in logcat with a nullpointer exception.  if u realise, the first time it needs the context is on `progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.fragment.getActivity());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `this.fragment.getActivity()` with `this.activity` since you already have reference to the activity.

Technically, to make it a more reusable and decoupled class I would replace the reference to `MainActivity` and simply call it `Context` since that's really all you need it for and don't really care if it's the MainActivity or some other Activity that this later lives on.

Comment: in the end i used context.

Answer (score 1):

Instead

```
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.fragment.getActivity());
```

use

```
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
```

Comment: This is also a good answer but i was getting some problems around `fragment.handleGetDirectionsResult(result);`